# JNI error while creating external table using gphdfs protocol : greenplum

Tags: greenplum

1) Completed "One-time HDFS Protocol Installation" using link - http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/4360/admin_guide/load/topics/g-one-time-hdfs-protocol-installation.html#topic20

2) copied the 'csv' file on hdfs system at path - `data/etl/ext01`

3) created external table using following command
`create external table orgData(orghk varchar(200),eff_datetime timestamp, source varchar(20), handle_id varchar(200), created_by_d varchar(100), created_datetime timestamp)
location ('gphdfs://<hostname>:8020/data/etl/ext01/part-r-00000-3eae416a-d0ff-4562-a762-d53469d42cd2.csv')
Format 'CSV' (DELIMITER ',')`

However after executing the command - select * from orgData
I am getting following error

```
ERROR: ERROR: external table gphdfs protocol command ended with 
error. Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your 
installation and try again (seg1 slice1 
<hostname2>:40000 pid=4977) Detail:  

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat   at 
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)  at 
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)  at 
java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)  at 
java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)     at 
java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)  at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.valid Command: 
'gphdfs://<hostname>:8040/data/etl/ext01/part-r-00000-3eae416a-d0ff-4562-a762-d53469d42cd2.csv' 
External table orgdata, file 
gphdfs://<hostname>:8040/data/etl/ext01/part-r-00000-3eae416a-d0ff-4562-a762-d53469d42cd2.csv
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify you set `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_HOME` on *ALL* segments, then restarted the cluster?

```
gpssh -f clusterHostfile -e 'egrep (JAVA_HOME|HADOOP_HOME) ~/.bashrc | wc -l'
```

You should see the number `2` from each host in the cluster.